# how to open "how do you want to open this file" dialog in c#?

Tags: c#

I would like to open the following dialog for a file in c#

[file dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7fHz.png)

Some post suggest Process.Start

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Process.Start(@"d:\1.abc");
    }
```

But it doesn't work. It raise an exception:

> "The specified executable is not a valid application for this OS
> platform"

I want to open "how do you want to open this file" dialog with or without a standard application suitable for that file type.

Comment: gonna be a shell thing paging @Raymond Chen

Comment: Please elaborate on "doesn't work".

Comment: Gonna need more detail, chief.  Best guess is the OS already has a file association for the file you're trying to Process.Start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `UseShellExecute` property of `ProcessStartInfo`.

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = @"C:\path\to\file.txt";
startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
Process.Start(startInfo);
```